# CSS Label background Color setting - Only apply background color to Label Length

Tags: html, css

Need help with Label background setting. Below is my code which I am using . Please help me to get expected output as below mentioned image.

```css
$header=@"
<style>
@charset "UTF-8"; 
table
{
font-family:Arial;font-size:1em;width:45%;margin-left:1px; margin-bottom:5px;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td 
{
font-size:1em;text-align:center;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;
border:0.8px solid MignightBlue;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding-bottom:5px;
}
th 
{
font-size:1.2em;font-weight:normal;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-left:0px;
background-color:DarkslateGray;
color:snow;
}
name tr
{
color:#F00000;
background-color:snow;font-size:0.8em;font-family:Arial;
}
</style>
"@


ConvertTo-Html -body "<H1 style=color:snow;font-weight:normal;background-color:DarkslateGray;font-size:1.5em;font-family:Arial;text-align:left;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100%>
 Database Consolidated Health Check Report </H1>" |`
 Out-File  C:\Temp\ConsolidatedReport.html
```

Current Output:

[image]

Expecting Output:

[image]

Comment: `display: inline-block`?

Comment: try to use `display: table`

Comment: May be use display:inline.. If the content gets two lines it will adjust..

Answer (score 2):

> Its due to block property of `h1` tag ,Using `display:table` you can
>   achieve desire result

```css
$header=@"
<style>
@charset "UTF-8"; 
table
{
font-family:Arial;font-size:1em;width:45%;margin-left:1px; margin-bottom:5px;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td 
{
font-size:1em;text-align:center;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;
border:0.8px solid MignightBlue;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding-bottom:5px;
}
th 
{
font-size:1.2em;font-weight:normal;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-left:0px;
background-color:DarkslateGray;
color:snow;
}
name tr
{
color:#F00000;
background-color:snow;font-size:0.8em;font-family:Arial;
}
h1{
 display: table;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
</style>
"@


ConvertTo-Html -body "<H1 style=color:snow;font-weight:normal;background-color:DarkslateGray;font-size:1.5em;font-family:Arial;text-align:left;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100%>
 Database Consolidated Health Check Report </H1>" |`
 Out-File  C:\Temp\ConsolidatedReport.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add "display: inline-block;" property in h1. Try below code:

```
ConvertTo-Html -body "<H1 style=color:snow;font-weight:normal;background-color:DarkslateGray;font-size:1.5em; display: inline-block; font-family:Arial;text-align:left;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100%>
```

Database Consolidated Health Check Report " |`
 Out-File  C:\Temp\ConsolidatedReport.html

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is Use `span` inside h1 tag

```css
h1 span{
background: #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Database Consolidated Health Check Report</span></h1>
```